# Remote API method won't create records based on received params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions

I have an api for mass creating records of a model Series. A remote machine sends a POST request to my url, with an array `@series` passed as a json parameter, like this:

```
@series = [{:id=>1,name:"test"}, {:id=>2,name:"test2"}]
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(post_uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
req.body = {series: @series}.to_json
res = http.request(req)
```

but I cannot for the life of me get the respective Series to be created. Here is the method that receives the data and is supposed to create one Series for each hash in the `@series` array:

```
  def api
    series = params[:series]
    series.each do |s|
      name = s[:name]
      if !Series.where(name: name).exists?
        Series.create(s)
      end
    end
  end
```

The params are definitely passed through, but no Series are created. When I check my logs there's a 500 error, but since it's remote, I have no way of getting a more specific error.

When I remove the params and just create a generic Series for each hash in the `@series` array, it works. For example, with the following code, if `@series` has 3 hashes, 3 Series are created:

```
  def post_product_data
    series = params[:series]
    series.each do |s|
      name = s[:name]
      if !Series.where(name: name).exists?
        Series.create  #GENERIC SERIES NOT BASED ON PARAMS
      end
    end
  end
```

I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I tried permitting all params. But when I changed the method to this, I got a `"undefined method "permit!"` error:

```
  def post_product_data
    series = params[:series]
    series.each do |s|
      name = s[:name]
      if !Series.where(name: name).exists?
        Series.create(s.permit!)  #TRIED PERMITTING ALL PARAMS
      end
    end
  end
```

Anyone have any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I changed the offending line to this:

```
Series.create({id: s[:id], name: s[:name]})
```

and now it works. I have no idea why, since the hashes should have been inserting the exact same thing. But at least it works finally.

Comment: In your `Series.create(s)` here **s** contains the `id` parameter which is default handled by the database. May be that's a issue. Try - `Series.create({name: s[:name]})`

Comment: programming a service and having no way to see errors is kind of crazy. Are you 100% sure there's no way? Is there somethinng special with the platform you're deploying to?

Comment: create a generic Series for each hash in the @series, could you show us the generic series that you have created.?

Comment: @Gabbar It just runs 'Series.create' for each hash, so each Series has an id, but everything else is nil.

Comment: @Emu You were on the right track. It's important for my app to specify the id when creating each Series, so I changed it to `Series.create({id: s[:id], name: s[:name]}), and it finally works. I have no idea why, since the hashes should have been inserting the exact same thing, but that's coding for you.